# Frida not hook functions

Tags: android, frida

I want to hook a xxtea_decrypt
but it not trigger and on other games it trigger but some games not trigger it.
On ida pro its trigger the xxtea_decrypt but frida nope
here is the code that i using it

```
var nptr = Module.findExportByName("libcocos2dlua.so", "xxtea_decrypt");
function fn() {
  nptr = Module.findExportByName("libcocos2dlua.so", "xxtea_decrypt");
 // nptr = Module.findExportByName("libcocos2dlua.so", "luaL_loadbuffer");
  if (!nptr) {
    console.log("xxtea_decrypt cannot be found!");
    setTimeout(fn, 900);
  // } else {

  //   // console.log("xxtea_decrypt");

  } else {
    Interceptor.attach(nptr, {
     
    
      onEnter: function(args) {
       
        console.log("----------------BEGIN----------------");
        console.log("Key: ");
        console.log(hexdump(Memory.readByteArray(args[1], 5000),{
         offset: 0,
         length: 500,
         header: true,
         ansi: true
        }));

        console.log("sign:");
        console.log(hexdump(Memory.readByteArray(args[2], 12),{
            offset: 0,
            length: 12,
            header: true,
            ansi: true
        }));
      },
      onLeave: function(retval) {
        // console.log("Decrypt:");
        // console.log(hexdump(Memory.readByteArray(retval, 50),{
        //  offset: 0,
        //  length: 50,
        //  header: true,
        //  ansi: true
        // }));
        // console.log("-----------------END-----------------");   
      }
    })
  }
}
var timeout = setTimeout(fn, 500);
```

The following screen shot shows the `xxtea_decrypt` function in IDA:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the `xxtea_decrypt` function is exported by `libcocos2dlua.so`? If not your hook will never be installed and thus never trigger. Frida can also hook non-exported functions but that requires to do some address calculation.

Comment: its inside but not trigger it
do you have a way how to pause the game and resume it? without frida ?

Comment: That the method is inside the library was not the question. My question was if the function you want to hook is in the list of exported functions (check e.g. in iDA). Because if it is not your code can not work.

Comment: Yes its inside ida
https://imgur.com/a/xueQCze

Comment: Again that was not my question. Is the method listed on the `Exports` tab in IDA? `Module.findExportByName` requires the method be listed in the Exports section of the binary.

Comment: yes its inside here you can see
https://imgur.com/a/J7cDljY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145014/discussion-between-xbuyk987-and-robert).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the name of the function you want to hook is not `xxtea_decrypt` and because of this you can not hook it:

In your IDA scren shot the function is shown as `xxtea_decrypt(uchar *,uint,uchar *,uchar *)`.

That the function has not only a name but also argument types displayed means it is not a plain C function but instead a C++ function which uses name mangling.

Name mangling encodes the argument types in the function name, which means the function name displayed by IDA is not the real function name, but the demangled function name which is optimized for human readability.

You will see the real function name if you disable name mangling in IDA. You can find the option in the context menu of the function.

Most likely IDA will display the function name without demangling as `_Z13xxtea_decryptPhjS_jPj`. This is the real function name you have to use for hooking in Frida.

This function name I got from a library of the same name I found on the Internet, and the xxtea_decrypt function seems to have the same argument types as the one in your library, so the function may be the same but you should better check in IDA with disabled name mangling and copy the function name from there.

If you want to hook the xxtea_decrypt function you have to use this hook:

```
var nptr = Module.findExportByName("libcocos2dlua.so", "_Z13xxtea_decryptPhjS_jPj");
```